# linux apache / PHP read and write permissions

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I have a script/app in PHP that works for our office and I succesfully deployed it to another office. Now in a third office, a certain glob()-function returns an empty string.

All offices use debian stable, so the versions of the software packages should be the same. The best I can think of, is that the permissions on that particular directory are insuccifient.

This I have done already:

- add '/share' to the open_basedir directive inside the virtualhost without a trailing '/' to make it recursive -> verified to be working with phpinfo()
- set permissions on '/share': 'setfacl -Rm d:u:www-data:rwx,u:www-data:rwx /share' and subsequently I have remounted '/share' and restarted apache to make sure the new permissions are in use.  -> verified to be working with 'getfacl /share': confirms that www-data has read/write permissions to /share and all directories beneath it
- I have verified 'safe_mode' is off
- I have added www-data to the POSIX-group that owns '/share': 'chown -R username/groupname /share' and this is verified by 'ls -l'. The POSIX-permissions on that dir are 'drwxrws---+'

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Where the apache is installed..? externally or lampp and so..?
If so, modify your permissions using chmod 0644 for all your app folders such as /var/www/html/* , or /opt/lampp/htdocs/

Comment: apache, PHP, postgres etc. are all installed on the same machine. I tried chmodding '/share' to 0644, 0755, 0777, 1777 but the glob()-function still returns an empty string. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: I also tried the glob()-function on a directory inside /var/www/ and it returned the array, as it is documented. This has to be a permissions-problem...

Answer (score 0):

Found it, and of course it is so obvious that I could smack myself on the head. The folder containing '/share' had strict permissions and that was probably prohibiting the user 'www-data' to enter '/share'.
Thx for thinking with me...